# Re: Form validation not working

Tags: javascript, forms

I am a newbie regarding backend technology and want to thank you for your patience ahead of time. I am developing a website with php includes, in which one link is a contact form (see below). I need the fields in the forms to be validated using javascript (see below for my code). I am also using a local server (WAMP). When I load the page containing the form and enter the wrong amount of characters or leave the form fields blank, there is no error message. Any help is greatly appreciated...thank you again for your patience.

**php document(contact.php)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="form2.js"></script>

<?php require 'Includes/Header.php'; ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="contact-form">
    <h5>Contact Form</h5>
    <form method="post" action="contact.php">

    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email">

    <label for="message">Message:</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>


    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>         
        <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>


<?php require 'Includes/Footer.php'; ?>
```

**Javascript(form2.js)**

```
function validate(form){
    var name = form.name.value;
    var name = form.email.value;
    var name = form.message.value;

    if (name.length == 0 || name.length > 200)
    {
        alert ("You must enter a name.");
        return false;
    }

    if (email.length == 0 || email.length > 200)
    {
        alert ("You must enter a email.");
        return false;
    }

    if (message.length == 0)
    {
        alert ("You must enter a message.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: You're assigning to the variable `name` three times

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your calling the validate() function. Try something along the lines of:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

Follow this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp) from w3schools... it seems to be exactly what you are trying to do. You never assigned the values to variables either. Assign a name to the form (e.g., `name="myform"`) and reference the variables the same way in the example.

```
var name = document.form["myform"]["name"].value;
```